# how to configure the key expired event listener in redisson reactive api (spring boot project)

Tags: redis, spring-webflux, reddison

i am using spring boot web flux with redisson. I want to enable all key expired event in my application. i tried it this way. but it doesn't work.

```java
this.client.getTopic("__keyevent@*__:expired", StringCodec.INSTANCE)
        .addListener(String.class, new MessageListener<String>() {
            @Override
            public void onMessage(CharSequence channel, String msg) {
                //
            }
        });
```

I wish a help to resole this problem.

Comment: 1st issue is, you haven't subscribed to the listener

Comment: yes. what next?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1st issue is, you haven't subscribed to the listener. and the 2nd one is that you can't use `getTopic` to the pub-sub event if you use a pattern in redisson. you should use `getPatternTopic` method like this. and make sure to subscribe to the process finally. and the listener should be implemented from `PatternMessageListener` interface.

```java
        this.client
                .getPatternTopic("__keyevent@*__:expired", StringCodec.INSTANCE)
                .addListener(String.class, new PatternMessageListener<String>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onMessage(CharSequence pattern, CharSequence channel, String msg) {
                        System.out.println("pattern = " + pattern + ", channel = " + channel + ", msg = " + msg);
                    }
                })
                .subscribe();
```